# I cant pass two arguments in angular service to send roomId and file_name parameters to nodejs

Tags: node.js, angular, file-upload

I have this method in nodejs to save image1 in the current object room

```
saveImg: function(req, res) {
        // var roomId = req.room.sub;
        var file_name = req.params.id;
        console.log('idroom', roomId);
        var roomId = req.body._id;
        console.log('file_name', file_name);

        Room.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: roomId }, { image1: file_name }, { new: true }, (err, roomUpdate) => {
            if (err || !roomUpdate) {
                // Devolver respuesta
                return res.status(500).send({
                    status: 'error',
                    message: 'Error al guardar la habitación'
                });
            }
        });
        
        // Devolver respuesta
        return res.status(200).send({
            status: 'success',
            image1: file_name,

        });
    },
```

service

```
  saveImg(image1):Observable<any>
  {
    console.log(image1);
   
    let params = JSON.stringify(image1);
    let headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type','application/json');

    return this.http.post(this.url + 'saveimg/'+params, {headers: headers});
  }
```

I can send from this service the.room.id and the.room.image1 the backend crash.

```
upload1(data)
    {
      //let data_obj = JSON.parse(image1.response);
      //this.room.image1 = data.body;
      console.log(this.room.id);

      this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe( params =>
        {
          console.log(params);
          console.log(params.id);
          let id = params['id'];
 
        
  


      


        this.room.id = id;
        console.log(this.room.id);
        this.room.image1 =  data.body.image1;
        console.log(this.room.image1);
        this.roomservice.saveImg(this.room.image1).subscribe(
          response =>
            {
              
            },
            error =>
            {
              console.log(error);
            }
    
        );

      });
```

this function upload1() get the this.room.image1 from the backend but I dont know to pass the room id (current room updating) and this.room.image1 to save in current room the image1.

Comment: I think the `http.post()` takes 3 arguments, not 2. So you would need something like `this.http.post(this.url + 'saveimg/'+params, null, {headers: headers})` Or you could pass the image params in as a value `this.http.post(this.url + 'saveimg/', params, {headers: headers})`

Comment: I need to pass roomId and image1 saveImg(id,image1):Observable<any>
  {
    console.log(image1);
   
    let params = JSON.stringify(image1);
    let headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type','application/json');

    return this.http.post(this.url + 'saveimg/'+id,params, {headers: headers}); this doesnt works

Comment: what does your backend look like? You say it keeps on crashing, but you might not be passing it the data formatted in a way it is expecting.